# What does mean if (\false) (yes, with backslash) in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

This morning, I've been notified that a new [Twig_Extensions](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions) release is available! Yay!

Before integrating it to [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com), I wanted to see [changes](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/pull/204/files). This is mainly adding support to namespaces using [`class_alias`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.class-alias.php) function, and then add PSR-4 correspoding classes that just include the legacy one.

But each new (namespaced) classes are implemented like this:

```
<?php

namespace Twig\Extensions;

require __DIR__.'/../lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php';

if (\false) {
    class TextExtension extends \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
    {
    }
}
```

What does this notation mean?

Comment: It means that the constant `false` is defined in the global namespace

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

Comment: I understand what it means - but in this case it seems to say - don't use this class definition.  Or am I missing something?!

Comment: Sure it is, the guy who wrote that code will soon move all code from Text class in Text.php inside the given new class and remove the if. Kind of a hack to prepare the ground.

Comment: You basically answered your own question in the question ;-) "namespace".

Comment: The true question is "What is the differences between `\false` and `false`" ... in the google [API-classes](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/c925552c84ca5cf02e36b83e72b5371ec3bea391/src/aliases.php#L44) is the same code.

But because `false` never can have a namespace it seams to be totally useles to prefix it with slash.
Can anybody tell if there is a difference when it is prefixed with slash ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means it's using the false defined in the global namespace..

After a bit of research it turns out the rest of this answer is nonesense... I could swear you were able to do this in PHP at one point in time.

I think this is get around the situation where

```
<?php
namespace whywouldyoudothis;

false = true;
?>
```

I have never ever seen anyone code for this but that's what springs to mind.

Comment: OMG! I love PHP 

Comment: Actually built-in constants like `true`, `false` or `null` cannot be redefined in namespaces - doing so results in fatal error (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.builtinconst). So prefixing them with backslash does nothing (and has no sense).

Answer (score 3):

From [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)

> Prefixing a name with \ will specify that the name is required from
>   the global space even in the context of the namespace.

Comment: I think the same. the big question is: When it make no sence to prefix a `false` with a slash, why somebody is writing such code?

Even in [Google API-classes](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/c925552c84ca5cf02e36b83e72b5371ec3bea391/src/aliases.php#L44) they use a `\false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (\false) {
    class TextExtension extends \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
    {
    }
}
```

The code is still reachable by code sniffers and IDEs. However I think it should have deprecation note there. So that developers would be notified about using deprecated classes.

Here is an example from main Twig repository.
https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v2.10.0/lib/Twig/Token.php

Answer (score 1):

This is a no sense code, simply this is a [Unreachable code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code) because \false is always false!