# what is the idea behind this kind of syntax found in the twig project?

Tags: php

I was studying a popular PHP template engine and found the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Twig;

class_exists('Twig_Lexer');

if (\false) {

    class Lexer extends \Twig_Lexer
    {
    }
}
```

I understand the part of `namespace` and also `'\false'` **but I don't understand what the idea behind using `class_exists` without assigning it to a variable or using it in a conditional structure**. Moreover I don't really understand the purpose of `if(\false){...}` there .

**Are the `if` statement and the `class_exists` related in some way? My question is clear .It is not about the `\` before the false but the class_exists**

Comment: `\\` indicates the global namespace

Comment: It is still interesting - why they use class_exists ...

Comment: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/2507#commitcomment-24149817

Comment: THANKS to you @madflow .Many of those who are on this site never take the time to really answer questions they just need to show that they are the great moderators but sometimes they are just completely wrong and unclever...You understand what i asked and this is intelligence...

Comment: This question is not duplicate at all .It is really not the same thing and the answer of your other question is somewhere nonsense as PHP manual stated that we can't redefine the constant like false, true, null,etc...The real answer of my question is what madflow has said @RiggsFolly

Comment: Hi, no need to get your panties in a bunch. A simple request to take a second look is all you need to do

Comment: I don't like when people downvoted questions as soon as they see the duplicate flag @RiggsFolly...They need to take a look carefully before downvoting anyhow

Comment: Ok, in that case you have to take a little more care to ask the question so there is no confusion about what you are asking. :)

Comment: Ok sorry for not being clear  early...

Comment: Are you or @madflow going to create an answer for this then. That github link does not really explain very well why the `class_exists('Twig_Lexer');` exists there in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Madflow pointed [here](http://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/2507#commitcomment-24149817)

They used the `class_exists` without assigning it to variable nor using its return value in conditional structure because its only purpose there is to:

> first trigger the autoloader for these classes and once they are
>   autoloaded, the alias is registered as well. And this means that child
>   classes using the alias for the typehint are not considered as
>   breaking the signature anymore...

Comment: Okay, but why is the `if(\false)` used? I mean the code in the body of the condition block will never be called, or am I wrong?

Comment: @naitsirch if(\false) could mean if(true) if  someone redefines global false constant  as true

Comment: That's not what I meant. A static 'false' in a if condition will never get true, right? The code within the if block (`class Lexer extends \Twig_Lexer { }`) will never be executed. So why does it exist at all?

Comment: Maybe for letting IDEs or static analyzers know about the class? [Update] at least somebody had the same idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56312242/1119601